# what is the work around for User!UserID when creating data driven subscription

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a report that uses User!UserID. But "Data Driven Subscription" cannot be created on reports using the "User Collection" or having data source with Windows Integrated Security. What is the work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work around is provided here http://www.fits-consulting.de/blog/PermaLink,guid,12db87cf-9d2f-4a2f-9f1b-a6cc1f692ea7.aspx.

Many thanks to Markus Fischer.